# Timing C# code using Timer

Tags: c#, algorithm, time, code-analysis

Even though it is good to check performance of code in terms of algorithmic analysis and Big-Oh! notation i wanted to see how much it takes for the code to execute in my PC. I had initialized a List to 9999count and removed even elements out from the them. Sadly the timespan to execute this seems to be `0:0:0`. Surprised by the result there must be something wrong in the way i time the execution. **Could someone help me time the code correct?**

```
        IList<int> source = new List<int>(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++)
        {
            source.Add(i);
        }

        TimeSpan startTime, duration;
        startTime = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads[0].UserProcessorTime;

        RemoveEven(ref source);
        duration = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads[0].UserProcessorTime.Subtract(startTime);

        Console.WriteLine(duration.Milliseconds);
        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most appropriate thing to use there would be `Stopwatch` - anything involving `TimeSpan` has *nowhere near* enough precision for this:

```
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// something to time
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

However, a modern CPU is very fast, and it would not surprise me if it *can* remove them in that time. Normally, for timing, you need to repeat an operation a large number of times to get a reasonable measurement.

Aside: the `ref` in `RemoveEven(ref source)` is almost certainly not needed.

Comment: So my code was correct but the tool used for measurement was wrong? So are classes passed always by reference in c#?

Comment: @Deeptechtons any variable/parameter/field to a class instance *is* a reference, so you are ***passing a reference***. By adding a `ref`, you are passing a reference, *by-reference* - which is only useful if you ***reassign*** the list in the method.

Answer (score 4):

In .Net 2.0 you can use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class

```
IList<int> source = new List<int>(100);
for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++)
{
    source.Add(i);
}

Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

watch.Start();
RemoveEven(ref source);
//watch.ElapsedMilliseconds contains the execution time in ms
watch.Stop()
```

Comment: the shorthand of `var stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); stopwatch.Start();` is `var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to previous answers:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// instructions to time

sw.Stop();
```

`sw.ElapsedMilliseconds` returns a long and has a resolution of:

**1 millisecond = 1000000 nanoseconds**

`sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` returns a double and has a resolution equal to the inverse of [Stopwatch.Frequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency.aspx). On my PC for example `Stopwatch.Frequency` has a value of `2939541` ticks per second, that gives `sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` a resolution of:

**1/2939541 seconds = 3,401891655874165e-7 seconds = 340 nanoseconds**