# Best way to time events in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, debugging

In Visual Studio, I am contantly wondering how long code takes to execute. Normally I do this:

```
var timer = new Stopwatch();

// run some code 

timer.Start();
timer.Stop();
```

Is there an option to do this the same way that breakpoints work in visual studio? I get that this might not be possible because multiple threads, but it would even two aditional breakpoints that acted as A timer start / stop would be cool either in vs or by extension.
Does this exist?

Comment: [Profiling documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019)

Comment: You misplaced your code placeholder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timing C# code using Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811039/timing-c-sharp-code-using-timer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Diagnostics Tools - Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/may/visual-studio-2015-analyze-performance-while-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015#performance-while-debugging) let you see how long each section of code took to run:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using breakpoint is to write a static timer method and output it to your logger of choice?

i came up with the following for a project of mine that outputs to Serilog. but you can adapt it to just Console.WriteLine() if you dont have a logger.

```
    public static Task LogExecutionTime(string? detail, Action action)
    {
        if (!Log.IsEnabled(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug))
        {
            action.Invoke();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        var methodName = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        action.Invoke();
        watch.Stop();

        var detailStr = detail is null ? string.Empty : "." + detail;
        Log.Logger.Debug($"{methodName}{detailStr}: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

example usage

```
 LogExecutionTime("Detail", () =>
 {
          // your code here
 }
```

**Edit to more generic implementation**

```
public static Task LogExecutionTime(Action action)
{
    var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    var methodName = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;

    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action.Invoke();
    watch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now}] {methodName}: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

example usage

```
 LogExecutionTime(() =>
 {
          // your code here
 }
```